# Chart.js bars have non uniform widths

Tags: chart.js, chart.js2

I have a simple bar graph, but every bar has a different width. Is there any way to make the bars' widths uniform and match the x axis units/grid spacing?

[image: Non uniform widths]

This is how my chart is defined:

```
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: chartData,
        options: {
            annotation: {
                annotations: []
            },
            legend: {
                display: false
             },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    type: 'time',
                    time: {
                        unit: 'day',
                        stepSize: 1,
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        maxTicksLimit: 21,
                        autoSkip: true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my chart.js version was slightly out of date. After I replaced it with the latest version (2.7.3) the bars suddenly looked fine.

Problem solved :-)